# How to make calendar date book python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Okay so im supposed to make a date book that prints out all the days of a month and changes per month cause they have different days and it has to use lists and two for loops here is what I have

```
monthNames = [ "", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ]

daysInMonth = ( 0,31,28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 )

for i in monthNames:
    for n in daysInMonth:


        print "%3s %8d _________________________________________"%(i,n)
```

So how do i get it to print a line for each day?

Comment: Why are you starting with "" and 0? Also why not use a dictionary?

Comment: Please provide an example of the output you desire.

Comment: Feb       1 _________________________________________
Feb       2 _________________________________________
Feb       3 _________________________________________
Feb       4 _________________________________________
Feb       5 _________________________________________
Feb       6 _________________________________________

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over the days of the month for each month. Instead, iterate over the range of days in the given month.

```
for month, days in zip(monthNames, daysInMonth):
    for day in range(1, days + 1):
        print "%3s %8d" % (month, day)
```

Comment: Zip sticks two sequences together: `zip([a, b, c], [1, 2, 3]) = [(a, 1), (b, 2), (c, 3)]`. It's designed for iterating over multiple sequences at the same time, just like you do here.

Comment: I got it to work making the following changes{}  
monthNames _______________________"%(month,day)= [  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ]

daysInMonth = ( 31,28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 )

for month, days in zip(monthNames, daysInMonth):
    for day in range( 1,days + 1):
        }